# Possibility of a custom Contacts field with a set list of values and Contacts lookup performance

Tags: android, performance, contacts

I'm pretty sure it's not viable to do what I'd like to based on some initial research, but I figured it couldn't hurt to ask the community of experts here in case someone knows a way.

I'd like to create a custom field for contacts that the user is able to edit from the main Contacts app; however, the user should only be allowed to select from a list of four specific values.  A short list of string values would be ideal, but an int with a min/max range would suffice.

I'm interested in knowing if it's possible either way, but also wondering if it make sense to go this route performance wise.  More specifically, would it be better to look up a contact (based on a phone number) each time a call or SMS message is received or better to store my own set of data (consisting of name, numbers, and the custom field) and just syncing contact info in a thread every so often?  Or syncing contacts the first time the app is run and then registering for changes using `ContentObserver`?

Here is a similar question with an [answer that explains how to add a custom field to a contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733589/how-to-add-new-fields-to-the-contact).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the purpose to have your own set of data against contacts **stored in your separate database**, as you obviously will run into sync issues. You can use the mimetype and store whatever you want against the contact, in the manner you linked.

Whenever you want to looup contacts you can do that by using your custom mimetype. You get the contact id (from `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`), and then you run another query to get the contact details (from `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`). Please note these are different tables.

> I'd like to create a custom field for contacts that the user is able to edit from the **main Contacts app**

I don't see that possible, editable from the main app, when you use your custom mimetypes, and you don't have much options here. The main contact app will display only the fields that are in SDK. You can store details against contacts but they won't show up in the inbuilt edit contact screen.