# Contact Custom Fields

Tags: android

Alright, I'm a little new to the Android SDK, so forgive me if my question doesn't make sense or is very trivial. I'd like to add a custom field for contacts, that contains the contacts username on a website I'm doing this app for.  And, with this custom field, I'd like to have the ability to click it (like "Send message" or "Call mobile") so that I can go to a specif Activity in my application, with a TextView set with the username that I just clicked on.

Sorry if that is a bit confusing, if you need anything else let me know!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add new field(s) to the contact?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733589/how-to-add-new-fields-to-the-contact)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically assign a picture (Bitmap) to a contact ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076197/how-to-programmatically-assign-a-picture-bitmap-to-a-contact)

Answer (score 4):

It's working! But I changed Data.CONTACT_ID to Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID here:

```
if (mod == 0) {
    values.put(Data.CONTACT_ID, this.getId());
    values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, clsContacts.FORMALITY_MIMETYPE);
    ctx.getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Comment: and also here:`int mod = ctx.getContentResolver().update(
                    Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    values,
                    Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + this.getId() + " AND "
                            + Data.MIMETYPE + "= '"
                            + clsContacts.FORMALITY_MIMETYPE + "'", null);`

Answer (score 3):

You have to creat your own mime type for those.

Here is an example that saves a boolean as my custom mime type to the contacts. It uses the latest SDK 2.1

```
public static final String MIMETYPE_FORMALITY = "vnd.android.cursor.item/useformality";
public clsMyClass saveFormality() {
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Data.DATA1, this.getFormality() ? "1" : "0");
            int mod = ctx.getContentResolver().update(
                    Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    values,
                    Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + this.getId() + " AND "
                            + Data.MIMETYPE + "= '"
                            + clsContacts.FORMALITY_MIMETYPE + "'", null);

            if (mod == 0) {
                values.put(Data.CONTACT_ID, this.getId());
                values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, clsContacts.FORMALITY_MIMETYPE);
                ctx.getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG(), "saveFormality failed");
        }
     return this;
    }

public boolean getFormality() {
     if (data.containsKey(FORMALITY)) {
        return data.getAsBoolean(FORMALITY);
    } else {
        // read formality
        Cursor c = readDataWithMimeType(clsContacts.MIMETYPE_FORMALITY, this.getId());
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    this.setFormality(c.getInt(0) == 1);
                    return (c.getInt(0) == 1);
                }
            } finally {
                c.close();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
public clsMyClass setFormality(Boolean value) {
    data.remove(FORMALITY);
    data.put(FORMALITY, value);
    return this;
}

/**
 * Utility method to read data with mime type
 *
 * @param mimetype String representation of the mimetype used for this type
 *            of data
 * @param contactid String representation of the contact id
 * @return
 */
private Cursor readDataWithMimeType(String mimetype, String contactid) {
    return ctx.getContentResolver().query(
            Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {
                Data.DATA1
            },
            Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactid + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "= '" + mimetype
                    + "'", null, null);
}
```

Usage is

```
objContact.setFormality(true).saveFormality();
```

Comment: whats the data in " if (data.containsKey(FORMALITY))"

Answer (score 0):

To add custom field you need to add custom mimetype in MIMETYPE table. But we dont have direct access to MIMETYPE table. so following can be done:

```
public static final String MIMETYPE="vnd.android.cursor.item/favsong";

         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id);
    values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE);
    values.put(Data.DATA1, "MyFavSong");
    Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

what we have done is  , we have created a custom MIMETYPE as string constant.
Then using insert query we are inserting a new row in Data table having RAW_CONTACT_ID of a person we want to associate our custom field , in MIMETYPE column we put our own mimetype and in DATA1 column we put favourite song .  here system internally add the new mimetype in MIMETYPE table and give it an ID and that ID is used in mimetype_id column of Data table.

Comment: Are you sure this code add the new field i tried this code but it replace my contact name with MyFavSong. Why?