# How to programmatically assign a picture (Bitmap) to a contact?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-contacts

I have a variable of type Bitmap and I would like to assign it to a Contact from my contact list as the CalledID picture, how would I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add new field(s) to the contact?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733589/how-to-add-new-fields-to-the-contact)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to creat your own mime type for those.

Here is an example that saves a boolean as my custom mime type to the contacts. It uses the latest SDK 2.1

**Important**

This example uses DATA1 for data, DATA1 is indexed but it's not recomended for binary data. 
In your case to store binary data such as Picture **you have to use DATA15**.

**By convention, DATA15 is used for storing BLOBs (binary data).**

```
public static final String MIMETYPE_FORMALITY = "vnd.android.cursor.item/useformality";
public clsMyClass saveFormality() {
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Data.DATA1, this.getFormality() ? "1" : "0");
            int mod = ctx.getContentResolver().update(
                    Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    values,
                    Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + this.getId() + " AND "
                            + Data.MIMETYPE + "= '"
                            + clsContacts.FORMALITY_MIMETYPE + "'", null);

            if (mod == 0) {
                values.put(Data.CONTACT_ID, this.getId());
                values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, clsContacts.FORMALITY_MIMETYPE);
                ctx.getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG(), "saveFormality failed");
        }
     return this;
    }

public boolean getFormality() {
     if (data.containsKey(FORMALITY)) {
        return data.getAsBoolean(FORMALITY);
    } else {
        // read formality
        Cursor c = readDataWithMimeType(clsContacts.MIMETYPE_FORMALITY, this.getId());
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    this.setFormality(c.getInt(0) == 1);
                    return (c.getInt(0) == 1);
                }
            } finally {
                c.close();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
public clsMyClass setFormality(Boolean value) {
    data.remove(FORMALITY);
    data.put(FORMALITY, value);
    return this;
}

/**
 * Utility method to read data with mime type
 *
 * @param mimetype String representation of the mimetype used for this type
 *            of data
 * @param contactid String representation of the contact id
 * @return
 */
private Cursor readDataWithMimeType(String mimetype, String contactid) {
    return ctx.getContentResolver().query(
            Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {
                Data.DATA1
            },
            Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactid + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "= '" + mimetype
                    + "'", null, null);
}
```

Usage is

```
objContact.setFormality(true).saveFormality();
```