# how to add new field (such as user@domain) in Contacts on Android API 2.1

Tags: android

Hi i am new to android , I hope so u guys will help me to obtain my requirement.

I am using an Android API Level 2.1

I need to create a new field such as user@domain not as e-mail format for every contacts. So i need to create a new MIME type now i got struck how to create this MIME type. Please help me to recover on implementing new MIME type to Contacts App.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Contact Custom Fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009839/contact-custom-fields)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733589/how-to-add-new-fields-to-the-contact

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement your own custom mimetype handler to show up in the default contact application. It won't show up there. But it will show up in your application if you do it.

For storing custom fields in contacts see that other two linked questions