# Adding new Custom Field of specific MIME type in Contacts App

Tags: android

I am using Android API 2.1.

Whether API's are available for adding new Custom field of Specific MIME type from an application.I have done through normal insertion of new contacts by this MIME type "vnd.android.cursor.item/asterix" and inserted on Data.Data1 .. Contact got inserted but not displaying any details please sort me out from this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations that you managed to store a custom mimetype data on a contact.

Unfortunately the built in Contacts applications won't display those fields for you. You will have to display it in your own application on your own UI elements.

Comment: i tried to retrieve using intent & startActivityForResult() api but application crashes please guide me to view my custom data.

Comment: Please see the answer on this thread for code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009839/contact-custom-fields

Comment: Thanx Pentium10 I have successed regarding storing of Custom field in Contact database, i also viewed my data through LogCat by printing it using "Cursor". Thanx for your snippet it helped me a lot. 

Can we view our Custom field from Main Contacts Application?

Comment: Unfortunately the built in Contacts applications won't display those fields for you.