# Contacts' custom fields not removed when app was uninstalled?

Tags: android, metadata, uninstallation, android-contacts

On Android, you can attach some metadata of your own to contacts, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009839/contact-custom-fields).

It works, but it seems that if the user has uninstalled the app, it still exists and you can fetch this data on the next run of the app (after being re-installed, of course).

My questions are:

1. How could it be?
2. Shouldn't it considered junk and be removed? It reminds me of the registry idea of windows OS, where apps leave traces behind them even after being uninstalled.
3. Would other apps be able to access/modify this data?
4. What's the purpose of this extra data anyway?
5. Do you know of other apps that do the same?
6. Do the mimeType have to be of the format "vnd.android.cursor.item/YOUR_APP"? what happens if the "YOUR_APP" is already taken?