# Add custom field to contact in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, mime-types, android-contacts

I'd like to add an custom field to contacts for permission management in my app.

f.e. Contact => Name, Number, Permission ("allowed"/"denied")

In my App I have a part which can receive commands by SMS.
Now I want to add a "Permission Management".
So that SMS from users, which are not allowed to send commands, not would be processed.

The "Permission Management" I'd like to realize with a custom field in the contactlist.

f.e. Contact => Name, Number, Permission ("allowed"/"denied")

**Who can I add (programmatically) a custom filed to a contact?**

(look at method "AddFieldtoContact" in ContactHelper.cs)

I found a solution where a custom mime type must be added: [How to add new field(s) to the contact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733589/how-to-add-new-fields-to-the-contact)

**How can I add a custom mime type to add it in a contact?**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
File StatusInAppPermission.cs

namespace Appname.Models
{
    public class StatusInAppPermission
    {
        public const string Allowed = "allowed";
        public const string Denied = "denied";
        public const string NotSet = "notset";

        public string Status = "";

        public StatusInAppPermission(string sta)
        {
            switch (sta)
            {
                case Allowed:
                    Status = Allowed;
                    break;

                case Denied:
                    Status = Denied;
                    break;

                case NotSet:
                    Status = NotSet;
                    break;

                default:
                    Status = NotSet;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
File Contact.cs

namespace Appname.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public StatusInAppPermission StatusPermission { get; set; }
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
File ContactHelper.cs

using Android.Provider;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Appname.Interfaces;
using Appname.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Appname.Droid.ContactHelper))]
namespace Appname.Droid
{
    class ContactHelper : IContactHelper
    {
        public async Task<List<Contact>> GetDeviceContactsAsync()
        {
            Contact selectedContact = new Contact();
            List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

                var uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri;
                //TODO: Add element for custom field "AppnamePermission"
                string[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number /*, custom field "AppnamePermission" */ };
                var cursor = Forms.Context.ContentResolver.Query(
                    uri,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.DisplayName + " ASC");

                if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        // Get StatusInAppPermission from contact if saved
                        string status = "";

                        try
                        {
                            //TODO: Get custom field "AppnamePermission" value if exists
                            status = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[3]));
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) { }

                        // Create new contact-object and add it to a List
                        contactList.Add(new Contact()
                        {
                             Id = cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0]))
                            ,DisplayName = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1]))
                            ,Number = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[2])).Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "")
                            ,StatusPermission = new StatusInAppPermission(status)
                        });
                    } while (cursor.MoveToNext());
                } 

            return contactList;
        }

        public async Task<Contact> GetDeviceContactByNumber(string Number)
        {
            Contact selectedContact = new Contact();
            List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

            contactList = await GetDeviceContactsAsync();

            foreach (Contact c in contactList)
            {
                if (c.Number.Equals(Number))
                {
                    selectedContact = c;
                }
            }

            return selectedContact;
        }

        public void AddFieldtoContact(Contact contact, string fieldname, string fieldvalue)
        {
            int ContactId = contact.Id;
            // f.i. add fieldvalue by ContactId and fieldname
            // fieldname => mimetype
            // replace "clsContacts.FORMALITY_MIMETYPE" with mimetype
            // the following code is adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733589/how-to-add-new-fields-to-the-contact

            try
            {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                
                int mod = Forms.Context.ContentResolver.Update(
                         uri
                        ,values
                        ,Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId + "=" + ContactId + " AND "
                                + Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype + "= '"
                                + clsContacts.FORMALITY_MIMETYPE + "'", null);

                if (mod == 0)
                {
                    values.Put(Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId, ContactId);
                    values.Put(Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype, clsContacts.FORMALITY_MIMETYPE);
                    Forms.Context.ContentResolver.Insert(uri, values);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                
            }
        }

        public string GetFieldFromContact(Contact contact, string fieldname)
        {
            int ContactId = contact.Id;
            string fieldvalue = "";

            // f.i. get fieldvalue by ContactId and fieldname

            return fieldvalue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some problem at AddFieldtoContact method? What is clsContacts.FORMALITY_MIMETYPE, I think you enter fieldvalue in this place, the fieldvalue is Allowed or Denied or NotSet.

Comment: @CherryBu yes, my problem is in “AddFieldToContact”. I probably made a mistake by copy & paste. The fieldvalues are probably “saved” in the variable “values” which is filled by the method “Put()”. I think the line “int mod = ... ContentResolver...” will check if there is a field with the specified mime type (“clsContacts.Formality_mimetype”). Like I wrote in the comment in the code, I have adapted this code and didn’t found out, what’s “clsContacts” is. I think it’s a selfdefined mimetype. (Do you know how to define that?) I think it’s used in the query to filter the fields (by type)